# ¿Cómo hacer que el usuario tenga que abrir ejecutable necesariamente como administrador?

Tags: python, windows

Estoy haciendo un rickroll (que probablemente nunca use, es básicamente para seguir aprendiendo a programar), y uso un BlockInput, para lo que necesito acceder a user32. Y para acceder necesitas ejecutar el programa como administrador. Sin eso, el programa no tiene sentido. Por cierto, lo voy a convertir en ejecutable (lo digo por si eso influye en el método que usar).

Alguien sabe como "obligar" al usuario a abrir como administrador, y que si rechaza, se cierre el programa?

El código es este:

```
import webbrowser
import time
from ctypes import *
import pyautogui


ok = windll.user32.BlockInput(True)

for i in range(20):

    webbrowser.open("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ")
    time.sleep(3)

ok = windll.user32.BlockInput(False)
pyautogui.press('f')
ok = windll.user32.BlockInput(True)
time.sleep(30)
webbrowser.open("https://docs.google.com/document/d/1uHPDMK7ebV2Pbbe2GVkqjSJldM3YK5uPHi6Pvteq4ZY/edit") 
time.sleep(20)

ok = windll.user32.BlockInput(False)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes probar a hacer algo como esto:

```
import ctypes, os

def checkPermissions():
    try:
        permission = (os.getuid() == 0)
        return permission
    except AttributeError:
        permission = ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin() != 0
        return permission
    


if checkPermissions():
    #la lógica de tu código en el caso de que sea una ejecución como administrador
else:
    os._exit(0)
```

Donde está el comentario de la lógica, ahí puedes meter la lógica que necesites, solo entra si se ejecuta el proceso como administrador. Por el contrario, si es un usuario normal, pasamos al exit y cerramos el proceso.

Espero que te sirva, si no es así, coméntame e intentamos ver una alternativa.

***Añado la opción de la negación primero de @franmost que aportó en los comentarios***

De esta forma, evitamos el identado del código. Además de ser una práctica común el realizar la negación primero.

```
import ctypes, os

def checkPermissions():
    try:
        permission = (os.getuid() == 0)
        return permission
    except AttributeError:
        permission = ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin() != 0
        return permission
    


if not checkPermissions():
    os._exit(0)

#la lógica de tu código en el caso de que sea una ejecución como administrador
```

Comment: También podrías negar tu condición y poner el `os._exit(0)` en el `if`, dejando la "lógica de tu código" tras él sin tener que agregar indentación innecesaria para el resto del programa.

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo @franmost, buen apunte!

Comment: Muchas gracias!